Stata - Using geonear command to find nearest neighbour within a group
I am trying to find the nearest neighbour using the geonear command in Stata conditional on observations sharing the same group. For example, matching individuals to their nearest neighbour (in kms) who shares the same gender. Below is an example of trying to match "cell towers" that share the same group identifier. This is adapted from the description in the geonear help file to try and tackle this. But I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do it instead of looping over the groups.
set obs 1000
gen ctid = _n
gen double ctlat = 37 + (41 - 37) * uniform()
gen double ctlon = -109 + (109 - 102) * uniform()
sort ctid 
g ctgroup = ceil(ctid / 10) // group cell towers into groups of 10
sum ctgroup
local G = `r(max)' 
tempfile cell
save `cell',replace 

forvalues j=1(1)`G'{
        use `cell' , clear 
        keep if ctgroup == `j'
        tempfile cell`j'
        save `cell`j'' , replace 
        geonear ctid ctlat ctlon using `cell`j'', n(ctid ctlat ctlon)  ignoreself
        save `cell`j'' , replace 
}

use `cell1'
forvalues j = 2(1)`G'{
    append using `cell`j''
}

